# How to change the default boolean value in Laravel migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

how can I change the default of boolean
for example instead of `Yes/No` I want to change it to `elibrary/evideo`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('elibrary', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('lm_ref_no',20)->comment('Learning Material No')->unique();
        $table->string('lm_desc',50)->comment('Learning Material Description');
        $table->boolean('section_posted')->comment('Section Posted')->default(true);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possible value of a boolean in a database can be 1/0 or true/false, if you want to get a custom value out of a boolean I would suggest you use Mutators: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators .

It would look something like this:

```
    public function getSectionPostedTransformedAttribute()
    {
        $result = "";

        if($this->section_posted == true) {
            $result = "elibrary";
        }

        if($this->section_posted == false) {
            $result = "evideo";
        }

        return $result;
    }
    
    //You can access the new value this way:
    $model->sectionPostedTransformed;
```

A cleaner way to do it:

```
    public function getSectionPostedTextAttribute()
    {
        return $this->section_posted ? "elibrary" : "evideo";
    }
```